# How to verify the user's email through the client part of the application in the service Firebase

Tags: python, firebase-authentication

```
def sign_up(self, email, password):

    app = App.get_running_app()
    signup_url = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=" + self.wak
    signup_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
    try:
        sign_up_request = requests.post(signup_url, data=signup_payload)
        sign_up_data = json.loads(sign_up_request.content.decode())
        log.info(sign_up_request, sign_up_data)

        if sign_up_request.ok:
            refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']
            localId = sign_up_data['localId']
            idToken = sign_up_data['idToken'] # authToken
            app.lock = 0
            with open('refresh_token.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(refresh_token)

            constants.LOCAL_ID = localId # uid
            constants.ID_TOKEN = idToken
            data = {"user_telephone": "", "user_name": "", "user_lname": "", "user_email": email}

            my_data = json.dumps(data)
            self.create_user(my_data=my_data, idToken=idToken, localId=localId)

        if not sign_up_request.ok:
            error_data = json.loads(sign_up_request.content.decode())
            log.error(f'{error_data} {sign_up_request}')
            error_message = error_data['error']['message']
            app.root.ids['login_screen'].ids['login_message'].text = error_message
    except Exception as exc:
        app.error_modal_screen(text_error="Please check your internet connection!")
        log.error(exc)
```

This code assumes that the user can enter a non-existent email address and register. What I need is that after sending the data, the user receives a link to the e-mail - the activator of his account. There are mechanisms in firebase like - -

-- auth.generate_email_verification_link

but for this you need to do

-- firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

which in turn requires a SDK Certificate. But the certificate cannot be stored on the user side of the application... Most likely I'm not catching up with something. Please clarify!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know how user friendly and how safe, but in the end, using this function, the user sends a request for verification from the application, and in firebase he simply closed the read and edit rights for unverified users. In the application itself, with the help of shit and sticks, the user is not allowed anywhere until verification passes

```
def verification_request(id_token):
    payload = json.dumps({
        "requestType": "VERIFY_EMAIL",
        "idToken": id_token
    })
    r = requests.post("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode",
                      params={"key": constants.WAK},
                      data=payload)
```